# Django REST: Serializer create function request.user not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

The create function is giving me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Looks like request.user does not exist in this serializer. Is there a way to retrieve the user id in serializer? Or is this not possible?

```
class EmployeeQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeQuestion
        fields = (
            'id',
            'employee',
            'question',
            'attempted',
            'passed',
        )

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = EmployeeQuestionSerializer(employee=request.user.pk)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return serializer.save();

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.attempted = validated_data.get('attempted')
        instance.passed = validated_data.get('passed')
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: `create` has no `request` parameter, it only has a dictionary with data.

Comment: `request.user` is available in your `serializer.context` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039105/field-level-validation-with-request-user-in-django-rest-framework/63039444#6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can to pass the request object from views.py to this serializer

```py
serializer = EmployeeQuestionSerializer(queryset, context={'request':request})
```

then in serializers.py you can access that with self inside create:
`user=self.context['request'].user`

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually the first part isn't necessary, "self.context['request'].user.pk" works right away!